# How to incorporate hecksher ohlin model to uk leaving the single market

Tags: european-union

How do incorporate the theories listed above , into a question regarding the UK exit from the EU and SEM and it’s outcome from this.

Comment: this is way too broad question. You need to narrow it down. Answering this would literally require writing a book

Comment: For example the UK leaving the single market will have effects on their trade. How can I link any of the given theories to explain the effects.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.